# Replace '<BR>' with ' ' in VB

Tags: html, vb.net

**Problem:** I am trying to replace the carriage return with a space. So I have the following:

```
txt="This is a beautiful day!<BR>"
response.write(Replace(txt,"<BR>"," "))
```

And I would like the `<BR>` to be replaced with a space. The reason being is following the string, I would have text after the string. So like:

```
txt Blah Blah Easter Day!
```

I also tried the following:

```
<%Dim auth As String = "Reason"
Dim txt As String = " You may contact your provider for detailed information about your diagnosis or treatment. This could include the detailed codes and their meanings."
auth = auth.Replace("<BR>", " ")
Dim txt1 As String = auth + txt
Response.Write(txt1)
%>
```

The Reason is a field that contains text followed by a `<BR>`. I thought by using `replace` I could remove it without updating the field (which I do not want to do). Instead, what happens is the following:

```
Blah blah blah.
You may contact your provider....
```

How can I achieve:

```
Blah blah blah. You may contact your provider....
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried your `response.write` code? Do you get any errors?

Comment: @freginold Yes and I get no errors. What happen is the <BR> is not replace with the space and not sure why

Comment: What does your join/append look like?

Comment: Did you inspect the HTML to be sure the <BR> has not been removed? It could be that you just need to put in &nbsp; for the space to be visible.

Answer (score 1):

Your function looks correct; it should be removing the `<br>`.  However, there may also be a Visual Basic line break at the end of the text line.  Try adding this function below your current `replace` function to remove that line break, if it exists:

```
auth = auth.Replace(VbCrLf, "")
```

For completeness's sake, you can also add these:

```
auth = auth.Replace(VbCr, "")
auth = auth.Replace(VbLf, "")
```

Comment: I have a question, sorry, new to VB, what does vbCr,VbLf and so on stand for? and I will add that and see what happens. Thank You

Comment: @RobertoFlores Those are constants used in Visual Basic to represent end-of-line characters. `VbCr` is the carriage return character (like `\r`), `VbLf` is the line feed character (like `\n`), and `VbCrLf` is both of them together (like `\r\n`).

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something here?

```
    Dim txt = "This is a beautiful day!<BR>"
    txt = txt.Replace("<BR>", " ")
    MessageBox.Show(txt)
```